# Why Android uses resources from the higher resource instead of a lower?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

There is an app which I want to adopt to xhdpi resolution phones. So I made resources for that resolution and all went fine regarding the xhdpi phones.

I have a test mobile phone which is `normal hdpi` and the layout is now messed up (after I made fixes for xhdpi phones.

The layout structure looks like this:

*/res/drawable-hdpi

/res/drawable-normal-xhdpi

/res/layout

/res/layout-normal-xhdpi*

When I load the app on `normal hdpi` phone, I see that it uses layout from `/res/layout-normal-xhdpi` and images from `/res/drawable-normal-xhdpi`.

Shouldn't it use resources from the lower resource folder like `/res/layout` and `/res/drawable-hdpi`? It does not and I do not know why.

Comment: I think creating a new tag just for `android-layout-xhdpi` is a bit overkill :)

Comment: added `resources` tag, since it is mostly about providing/choosing resources.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Ok. sorry for that

Comment: @Arhimed, `resources` is an extremely, *extremely* general tag name... I think `android-resources` is better suited for this case too

Comment: @Alex Lockwood: ok, no problem, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) system eliminates resource files that contradict the device configuration, but it looks like your case is expected, because of this exception:

> **Exception:** Screen pixel density is the one qualifier that is not eliminated due to a contradiction.

This way a device of `normal hdpi` configuration matches to `/res/drawable-normal-xhdpi`.